# Encoding Response as Gzip Causing Cookie to Not Be Set in Browser

Tags: java, cookies, browser, gzip

I'm trying to reduce the network traffic by Gzipping all responses from backend, but I ran into an issue where cookie is not set in the browser if the login/logout call is being done the same way and I'm not sure why.

This is the backend code in Java.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie_name", cookieToken);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
response.addCookie(cookie);

response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
String json=serviceOutput.toString();
byte[] gzip = Utils.gzip(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
response.setContentLength(gzip.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(gzip);
```

Any pointer on why this doesn't work? I'm pretty sure I did the same thing previously without any issues.

--

#### Added the gzip method just in case it's relevant

```
public static byte[] gzip(byte[] content) throws IOException    {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream g = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);

    if (content != null && content.length > 0) {
        g.write(content, 0, content.length);
        g.close();
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting the cookie exactly?

Comment: I updated the question to include the code that set cookie.

Comment: hmm - you *do* know that most Servlet Containers support automatic gzipping of certain content-types? I think that would cause a lot less headache for dealing with response headers and stuff

Comment: What container are you using? Is the cookie included in the HTTP response?

Comment: Container is Jetty 9.4.0.v20161208. Cookie is not returned in the response header with gzip.

Comment: Is it Mozilla firefox you are working with?

Comment: The problem I have experienced is in Chrome and Safari. I have not tested in Firefox, but I would assume it's also not working.

Comment: Hi, what is `Utils.gzip` ? I've executed  your code in my machine but just used `GZIPOutputStream` to gzip output and used Spring Controller instead of plain Servlet and it works perfectly. So I guess your issue is not in code or maybe you don't sown all code.

Comment: Just added the gzip code. I'm pretty sure it's not relevant, but just in case.

Answer (score 9):

I have modified your code for mocking data as

```
package com.mytests.pack;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2638972063792556071L;
    private Cookie[] cookies;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        cookies = request.getCookies();

        System.out.println("----------------------======================-------------------");
        if(null!=cookies){
            for(Cookie c : cookies){
                System.out.println(c.getValue());
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("First request");
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------======================-------------------");

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie_name", "cookiecontentishereofname"+LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        String json="{\"keyone\":\"Somestring is here in the point\"}";

        ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzipstream = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);

        byte[] gzip = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
        gzipstream.write(gzip);
        gzipstream.close();
        response.setContentLength(obj.toByteArray().length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(obj.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

with **above code** and **jetty-distribution-9.4.0.v20161208**

- Tested Browsers

  -**Google Chrome** - `Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)` **`RESULT :cookie was set`**
   [image: screenshot]
   
  -**Opera** - `45.0.2552.812 (PGO)` **`RESULT :cookie was set`** 
  [image: screenshot]
  -**Mozilla Firefox** - `53.0.3 (32-bit)`

**Important thing to note about FIREFOX**
When you open developer tools it **doesn't show any cookie set** but **Practically works fine** check screenshots
[image: firefox cookie view]

**Where as**

 [image: Jetty console output]

**Jetty console output shows cookie was set successfully!**

other change in config I would like to show you

added `POM dependency snippet` as

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you saying that I need additional dependency for this to work?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work for me. There must be something else that is causing the issue since your code is exactly the same as mine unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @juminoz Are you modyfying default  CookieManager/CookieHandler?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks pretty ok. 
What I advice you is to show here the response plain text headers using for example `curl -v http://your.host/under/test` terminal command. 
If your cookie appears there, then it is a browser's thing